# Wordpress standard loop: additional post count with parameters

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am altering a template file of the Search & Filter Wordpress Plugin to show additional post counts.

The plugin uses the standard Wordpress loop to query posts by certain parameters. The number of posts can be counted by using `found_posts`.

Now I want to display a second post count that takes additional parameters into account, eg. `post_status`. I have to stick to the regular WP loop to keep the query from the Plugin intact.

Something like this in the commented line:

```
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

  echo $query->found_posts 'posts found';
  // echo $query->found_posts(array('post_status=>'private') 'private posts found';

  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    the_title();
  }
}
```

The code works fine, except for the commented part which obviously doesn't work.

Is there a way to add another `post_count` with additional parameters to the standard loop?

Thanks

Georg

Answer (score 0):

You could not add like this `echo $query->found_posts(array('post_status=>'private')` but before your loop just use below code to count posts by `status`. in your case you want to count posts by status private so add below code.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'your_post_type_name','post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'future', 'private', 'inherit', 'trash')    
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

  echo $query->found_posts 'posts found';

  // echo $query->found_posts(array('post_status=>'private') 'private posts found';
  $count_posts = wp_count_posts('post');
  $private_posts = $count_posts->private;
  echo $private_posts. 'private posts found';
  while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    the_title();
  }
}
```

similarly if you want to show count for publish or draft posts you can add below code.

```
$publish_posts = $count_posts->publish;
$draft_posts = $count_posts->draft;
```

you could count any other posts by its status is well.

Comment: Thanks @raju_eww but the result is always 0, although there are a few private posts and I am logged in. Guess the way the plugin handles the query interferes with the counting. Any idea of how to do this with post meta data instead of post status? Eg. 'meta_key' => 'color', 'meta_value' => 'red'

Comment: Hello i forgot to add `post` so please add it like `$count_posts = wp_count_posts('post');`. also have updated the answer

Comment: also have updated the answer and also what are the args you are passing in query is also important.

Comment: also tested and working too and updated the answer too.

Comment: Thanks @raju_eww! But I'm still getting an error for `$private_posts = $count_posts()->private;`: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string

Comment: could you please share whole code with your loop so ican help you further.